# Irreducibility of Faulhaber-like Polynomials over $\mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, factorization

**Motivation:** Inspired by the famous [Faulhaber polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula) $F_k(N)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^Nn^k,$ I decided to study their alternating versions, $\Phi_k(M)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^M(-1)^nn^k$.

---

For $k\ge2$ and even values of $M=2N$ we have:

> $$\begin{align}\Phi_k(2N)~&=~N^{(k\bmod2)+1}~(2N+1)^{(k+1)\bmod2}~{\color{blue}{P_{_k}(N)}}\\\\&=~2^{k+1}F_k(N)-F_k(2N)\end{align}$$

For $k\ge2$ and odd values of $M=2N+1$ we have:

> $$\begin{align}\Phi_k(2N+1)~&=~-(N+1)^{(k\bmod2)+1}~(2N+1)^{(k+1)\bmod2}~{\color{blue}{Q_{_k}(N)}}\\\\&=~\Phi_k(2N)-(2N+1)^k~=~2^{k+1}F_k(N)-F_k(2N)-(2N+1)^k\end{align}$$

where $P_k$ and $Q_k$ are polynomials with **integer coefficients** of degree $k-2$ in $N$.

---

> My **conjecture**, based on computer aided verification for all values of $k\le10^3,$ is that $\color{blue}{P_k}$ and $\color{blue}{Q_k}$ are **irreducible** over $\color{blue}{\mathbb Q[x]}$. How could we either prove or disprove this statement ? Thank you!

**Appendix:** The explicit formulas for the first ten $P_k$ and $Q_k$ can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsrVe.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt6YA.png).

Comment: I see the lower bound for the index $n$ in the sum being zero. Is that really meant?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: As a matter of personal taste and preference, I always start at $n=0$, unless the zero-term is undefined. The fact that, in this particular case, it is redundant, hasn't even crossed my mind until you just brought it up. :-)

Comment: Ah, I agree. That's also my favorite index, btw., because I look at many of this problem with the view on matrices. However with that sum of powers-problems I let then start the series-definition with $(n+1)$ to avoid powers of zero and to allow easy generalizations *(of course the most simple one, series where the index is in the denominator)*

Answer (score 3):

It is known that the sum $\Phi_k(M)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^M(-1)^nn^k$ can be written by Euler polynomials and $F_k(N)$ can be written by Bernoulli polynomials.

Historically , Euler on page 499 of "L.Euler, Institutiones Calculi Diﬀerentialis, Petersberg,1755" ([Euler archive link](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/pages/E212.html)), introduced Euler polynomials, to evaluate the
alternating sum $\Phi_k(M)$

More precisely,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^p=\frac{1}{p+1}\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p+1}{k}B_kn^{p+1-k}$$

where $B_k$ are Bernoulli numbers and can be defined by following generating function

$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

See this paper for irreducibility for such polynomials

Duke Math. J.
Volume 19, Number 3 (1952), 475-481.
Note on irreducibility of the Bernoulli and Euler polynomials

L. Carlitz

http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077477373

Comment: Are you sure that's the right page number for the Instituones Calculi Differentialis?  I looked at https://math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/docs/originals/E212sec2ch11.pdf , but didn't find such a definition.