# Is $x^{2k+1} - 7x^2 + 1$ irreducible?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

> **Question.** Is the polynomial $x^{2k+1} - 7x^2 + 1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ for every positive integer $k$?

It is irreducible for all positive integers $k \leq 800$.

Comment: What's the motivation for asking this question?

Comment: @René motivation comes from various well studied directions: enriching the existing criteria for irreducibility, analogies with formulas for prime numbers (irreducibles in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$), the study of trinomials (and their Galois groups), and so on. Sometimes, polynomials similar to these pop-up in questions related to combinatorics and dynamics. I did not want to elaborate on these too much since the question is, in my opinion, of independent interest.

Comment: Could it be that the answer is yes if 7 is replaced by any odd prime?

Comment: @TimothyChow I believe that it could indeed be the case.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here is a proof, based on a trick that can be used to prove that
$x^n + x + 1$ is irreducible when $n \not\equiv 2 \bmod 3$.

We work with Laurent polynomials in $R = \mathbb Z[x,x^{-1}]$; note that
$R$ has unit group $R^\times = \pm x^{\mathbb Z}$.
We observe that for $f \in R$, the sum of the squares of the coefficients
is given by
$$\|f\| = \int_0^1 |f(e^{2 \pi i t})|^2\,dt
        = \int_0^1 f(e^{2 \pi i t}) f(e^{-2 \pi i t})\,dt
        = \int_0^1 f(x) f(x^{-1})\big|_{x = e^{2 \pi i t}}\,dt .$$
Now assume that $f(x) = g(x) h(x)$. Then, since
$f(x) f(x^{-1}) = \bigl(g(x)h(x^{-1})\bigr)\bigl(g(x^{-1})h(x)\bigr)$,
$G(x) := g(x) h(x^{-1})$ satisfies $\|G\| = \|f\|$
and $G(x) G(x^{-1}) = f(x) f(x^{-1})$.

Now we consider $f(x) = x^n - 7 x^2 + 1$; then $\|f\| = 51$.
If $f = g h$ as above, then write
$G(x) = \pm x^m(1 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots)$
and $G(x^{-1}) = \pm x^l(1 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + \ldots)$.
The relation $G(x) G(x^{-1}) = f(x) f(x^{-1})$ translates into
(equality of signs and)
$$(1 + a_1 x + \ldots)(1 + b_1 x + \ldots) = 1 - 7 x^2 + O(x^{n-2}).$$
Assuming that $n > 40$ and considering terms up to $x^{20}$, one can
check (see below) that the only solution such that
$a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \ldots + a_{20}^2 + b_1^2 + b_2^2 + \ldots + b_{20}^2\le 49$
is, up to the substitution $x \leftarrow x^{-1}$, given by
$1 + a_1 x + \ldots = 1 - 7x^2 + O(x^{21})$,
$1 + b_1 x + \ldots = 1 + O(x^{21})$. Since the $-7$ (together with the
leading and trailing 1) exhausts our allowance
for the sum of squares of the coefficients, all other coefficients
must be zero, and we obtain that $G(x) = \pm x^a f(x)$
or $G(x) = \pm x^a f(x^{-1})$. Modulo interchanging $g$ and $h$,
we can assume that $g(x) h(x^{-1}) = \pm x^a f(x)$,
so $h(x^{-1}) = \pm x^a f(x)/g(x) = \pm x^a h(x)$,
and $x^{\deg h} h(x^{-1})$ divides $f(x)$.
This implies that $h(x)$ divides $x^n f(x^{-1})$, so $h(x)$ must divide
$$f(x) - x^n f(x^{-1}) = 7 x^2 (x^{n-4} - 1).$$
So $h$ also divides
$$f(x) - x^4 (x^{n-4} - 1) = x^4 - 7 x^2 + 1 = (x^2-3x+1)(x^2+3x+1).$$
Since $h$ also divides $f$, it must divide the difference $x^n - x^4$,
which for $n \neq 4$ it clearly doesn't, since the quartic has no
roots of absolute value 0 or 1; contradiction.

The argument shows that $x^n - 7 x^2 + 1$ is irreducible for $n > 40$;
for smaller $n$, we can ask the Computer Algebra System we trust.
This gives:

**Theorem.** $x^n - 7 x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$
for all positive integers $n$ except $n=4$.

**ADDED 2017-01-08:**
After re-checking the computations, I realized that there
was a small mistake that ruled out some partial solutions prematurely.
It looks like one needs to consider terms up to $x^{20}$.
[Here](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/MO/MO-258914.magma) is a file with MAGMA code that verifies that
there are no other solutions.

Comment: That's amazing! do you have a reference for the original argument?

Comment: This looks awesome and potentially quite general! The first part can be expressed without integration in a way that to me is a little more intuitive: The identity $f(x) f(x^{-1}) = G(x) G(x^{-1})$ implies that the sum of squares of coefficients of $f(x)$ equals the sum of squares of coefficients of $G(x)$ because the sum of the squares of coefficients of $p(x)$ is the coefficient of $0$ in $p(x) p(x^{-1})$ by the obvious expansion.

Comment: @Pablo I found it on page 97 of Zannier's "Lecture notes on Diophantine Analysis" (footnote to exercise 3.20): "Selmer proved that actually $f_n$ is irreducible for such $n$. Here is a sketch of an argument due to Ljiungrenn. ..." Alas, there is no "Ljiungrenn" in MathSciNet or ZMATH. This should be "W. Ljunggren", and the original source appears to be this: http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10593/8614.

Comment: Ljunggren treats the case $x^n \pm x^m \pm 1$ in his paper (Theorem 3).

Comment: I am slightly confused by the condition $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \ldots + b_1^2 + b_2^2 + \ldots \le 49$. Why is it not $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \ldots\le 50$ and $b_1^2 + b_2^2 + \ldots \le 50$? I mean, we only know that $\|G\| = 51$.

Comment: The same method gives the irrducibility of $x^n - 11x^2 + 1$ for $n \neq 4$. The computation is more involved and needs to consider terms up to $x^{37}$. Some more experimentation shows that it proves that $x^n - mx^2 + 1$ is irreducible for $n > 4$ and $m = 3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13$.

Comment: @GHfromMO We consider initial segments of the coefficient vector of $G$ from both ends that do not overlap (this leads to the condition $n>40$), so the sum of squares of both together is bounded by the sum of squares of all coefficients of $G$.

Comment: @GHfromMO I have made this clearer in my answer.

Comment: Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be integer polynomials with constant term one. Consider all the ways to divide $a_1,\dots,a_n$ to two groups and multiply the elements of each group together, obtaining two polynomials. Let $c$ and $d$ be the pair of polynomials obtained where the sums of the squares of coefficients of both polynomials is minimal. Assume that furthermore they are unique, and that $c(x^{-1})$ and $d(x)$ relatively prime to each other and to $x$. It seems that your argument implies $f(x) = c(x^{-1}) x^N +d(x)$ is irreducible for $N$ large enough, where "large enough" is explicitly computable.

Comment: The first part is the same, with the key point being that if there is an alternate factorization for all finite powers with a given sum of squares, then by compactness there is an alternate factorization in power series with a given sum of squares, which must be a factorization in polynomials because there are only finitely many nonzero coefficients.

Comment: For the second part, given $G(x) = \pm x^a f(x)$, we observe that since $f(x)$ and $f(x^{-1})$ have no common roots, $h(x)$ and $h(x^{-1})$ have no common roots, so all common roots of $f(x)$ and $G(x)$ must be roots of $g(x)$, so $h(x)=1$. We can run the same argument if $G(x) = \pm x^a f(x^{-1})$, but it seems we also need to check that $f(x)$ and $f(x^{-1})$ have no common roots in general, so maybe I was a bit hasty.

Comment: I guess the point is any common roots of $c(x^-1) x^N + d(x)$ and $d(x^{-1}) x^N + c(x)$ must also be roots of $d(x^{-1}) d(x) - c(x^{-1}) c(x)$ and we can eliminate those finitely many roots by some explicit calculation.

Comment: @WillSawin (1) You probably want the $a_j$ to be irreducible, to exclude any further possibilities of factorization. (2) It is possible that some of the roots of $d(x^{-1})d(x) - c(x^{-1})c(x)$ are roots of $c(x^{-1})x^N + d(x)$ for infinitely many $N$, e.g., when $c = 1$, $d = 1+x$ and $N \equiv 2 \bmod 3$. (3) I like the compactness argument.

Comment: @MichaelStoll (1) Indeed I meant that. (2) Sure, but in any case it's totally explicit so we can compute in a finite amount of time an exact description of which polynomials are irreducible and which are not. (3) Thanks!

Comment: This looks similar to the proof I posted earlier for irreducibility of $x^n-x-1$ at math.stackexchange.com/questions/393646/irreducibility-of-xn-x-1-over-mathbb-q/393779

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56579/about-irreducible-trinomials (linked from the MSE thread KConrad mentions).

Comment: @MichaelStoll: Do you have any idea on how to tackle [these](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198174) two [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069008) ?

Comment: @Lucian The first, no; the second is answered (positively) by Ljunggren's paper linked in my first comment here.

Comment: @MichaelStoll: $~\dfrac{x^{6k+2}-x+1}{x^2-x+1}~$ is not a trinomial.

Comment: @Lucian ... but the numerator is, and Ljunggren tells you that when it is reducible, it is the product of two irreducible factors.

Answer (score 15):

Not an answer, but an observation, which, if proved, will probably give an answer.

For all $k$ that I have computed, your polynomial has two roots smaller than $1$ in absolute value (for large $k$ these converge to $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}.$), and the rest of the roots are larger than $1$ in absolute value. Let's assume this is true. Since the constant term of a factor has to have absolute value $1$ each factor should have one of these roots, so there are at most $2$ irreducible factors.

Comment: I think the claim that there are exactly two roots of absolute value less than 1 in $\mathbb C$) should follow from Rouché's theorem, since $|x^{2k+1}|  = 1 < 6 \le |-7x^2 + 1|$ on the unit circle.

Comment: True. Easier is (triangular inequality): $\vert x^{2k+1}+1\vert\leq 2<7=\vert 7x^2\vert$ on the unit circle.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I wouldn't necessarily think that $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$ is so much easier than $|a-b| \ge |a| - |b|$; they are just two equivalent formulations of the same fact.

Comment: I was just being picky. I agree. :-)

Comment: The remaining roots will converge to the roots of $x^{2k-1} - 7$, so will have absolute value close to $7^{1/(2k-1)}$. So we can expect it to be hard to find any number of these such that the product has absolute value sufficiently close to $\sqrt{7}$. If somebody can get sufficiently good estimates, this should lead to a proof.

Comment: The statement in the **ADDENDUM** is wrong (for example for $2k+1 = 19$, there are six factors of degree 3). If $2k+1 = p$ is prime, the degree of the nonlinear factors mod 7 is the order of 7 in the multiplicative group mod $p$, which does not have to be $p-1$. Assuming Artin's primitive root conjecture, we get at least infinitely many $k$ such that the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: @MichaelStoll Hmm, was too late at night - I removed it...

Comment: Re my last comment but one, it turns out that the convergence of the absolute value of the "large" roots divided by $7^{1/(2k-1)}$ to $1$ is too slow (error of order $1/k$) to deduce more than that any nontrivial divisor $h$ of $x^{2k+1} - 7 x^2 + 1$ would have to have "relative degree" $(\deg h)/(2k+1)$ in a fairly short interval around $1/2$.

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: I'm afraid that this answer is wrong and I hope you have some way of "unaccepting" it. The reason is that when taking conjugates of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}-\beta_1}$ we're allowed to freely change the sign of $\sqrt{7}$ (unless $\sqrt{7}$ is contained in the field generated by $\beta_1$, which seems rather unlikely). And $\frac{1}{-\sqrt{7}-\beta_1}$ is greater than $1$ in absolute value. I found this mistake only when I noticed that my "proof" gives that $x^4-7x^2+1=(x^2+3x+1)(x^2-3x+1)$ is irreducible. It should work with an integer square in place of $7$. Maybe someone can make it work also for $7$? I apologize for raising false hopes!

The question is equivalent (by replacing $x$ with $\frac{1}{x}$) to asking about the irreducibility of $A(x) = x^{2k+1}-7x^{2k-1}+1 = x^{2k-1}(x^2-7)+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. An application of Rouché's theorem shows that $A(x)$ has exactly $2k-1$ zeroes (counted with multiplicity) of absolute value less than $1$. There remain two real zeroes $\beta_1 < -1$ and $\beta_2 > 1$. One can deduce from the equation they satisfy that $|\beta_i - (-1)^i\sqrt{7}| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}+1}$ ($i=1,2$).

Now suppose that $A$ factorizes as $A = BC$ with monic integer polynomials $B, C$. Wlog $B(\beta_1) = 0$. If $B(\beta_2) \neq 0$, then
$$\beta_1^{2k-1}(\beta_1+\sqrt{7}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}-\beta_1}$$
is an algebraic integer, all conjugates of which are less than $1$ in absolute value (the right hand side is less than $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}+1}}<1$ and all its conjugates are of absolute value at most $\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}-1}<1$).

So it would have to be $0$, which is absurd. So $B(\beta_2)=0$. But now all roots of $C$ are less than $1$ in absolute value, while its constant term is $1$. It follows that $C=1$ is constant and so $A$ is irreducible.

Comment: I also completely missed the fact that when one considers Galois conjugates, it is possible also to conjugate $\sqrt{7}$ and not only $\beta_1$.

Comment: Well, you fooled me! :-) I thought I had read your proof very carefully.  So it's still instructive, [in a way](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94742/examples-of-interesting-false-proofs).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Well, this general method does prove irreducibility in certain cases. AFAIK, it originates in Ankeny, Brauer, Chowla, A Note on the Class-Numbers of Algebraic Number Fields, Amer. J. Math. 78 (1956), 51-61, and I used it to prove irreducibility in Lemma 4.1(b) of my article (https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/acta-arithmetica/online/91952/effective-approximation-and-diophantine-applications, sorry for the self-promotion, but I thought it might interest you).